# How to fix no matching function call to strstr

Tags: c++

So I keep getting this error, no matching function for call to `'strstr(str::string&, const char [2])'`

I've seen some ways to fix it by adding `.str().c_str();`

But this seems very hacky to me. Is there a more standard way of doing it for my given scenario:

```
 string resistance = stockIterator->getValue()->getOther();
                 if(strstr(resistance, "R")){
                    printf("Small resistance");
                    float first = atoi(strtok(resistance, "R"));
                    float second = atoi(strtok(NULL, " \n"));
                    second = second/10;
                    float num = (first+second)/1000000;
                    num = num * stockIterator->getValue()->getStockCount();
                    printf(" %.7f\n\n", num);
                    count = count + num;
```

Comment: Just use `c_str()` on `std::string`. It returns a `const char *` that the C stdlib can use.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True :-) was about to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use `std::string`'s `find()` member function. To get the substrings you can use `std::string`'s `substr()` member function and for the float conversion you can use `std::stof()`. Here's how you would do that:

```
string resistance = stockIterator->getValue()->getOther();
std::string::size_type pos = resistance.find("R");
if(pos != std::string::npos) {
    float first = std::stof(resistance.substr(0, pos));
    float second = std::stof(resistance.substr(pos+1));
    // other code 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting a very similar error for   `float first = atoi(strtok(resistance, "R"));`

Comment: @Blarsssss: The story there is exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you, getting 'stof' is not a member of 'std' , i'll accept your answer anyway and try figure this one out

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is that it is a function that is only available since C++11 (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). Maybe you need to add the `-std=c++11` flag to your compilation command.

Comment: Yeah i'm using code blocks so I've enabled `have g++ follow the c++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]` Still not working

Comment: Weird. Maybe you could use `atof(resistance.substr(0, pos).c_str())` instead. Does that work?

Comment: Still getting `atof was not declared in this scope`

Comment: And `atoi()` was working? I just started using `std::stof()` / `atof()` because it seemed like you want to parse a floating point number and not an integer because you assigned it to float variables.

Comment: Does your code contain `#include <cstdlib>` or `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: just added #include <cstdlib> and getting cammpt cpmvert strd:basic_string<char> to const char

Comment: Then use the `c_str()` member function to create a `const char *`.

Comment: Great! No problem:-)

Comment: just another quick  question, as I'm declaring  `string::size_type pos = resistance.find("R");` I have else ifs which I want to check for a different letter how would I encorporate that into it? because pos has already been chosen right?

Answer (score 1):

It's not "hacky" — `std::string::c_str()` gives you the C-string representation of your C++ string, which is your *only* option if you're mixing C++ strings and C library functions (such as `strstr`).

My best advice to you is to stop using C library functions in C++. You should be using `std::string::find` to locate the character `'R'` in a `std::string`.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I am coming from a C background!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)
[`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) is for C strings